# Firebug generated XPath not working, appears to be valid

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt-1.0

I am trying to get a particular field that only occurs once inside a xml file which always has the same format, which should have been a simple task.

The field I want is "MaterialDefinitionID", I've used firefox firebug to copy the xpath which worked for all the other documents I've done except this one. At first I thought the XPATH was 
something complicated that firebug didn't get right but it appears to be valid to me.

The XPATH I am using is: /CPS/DA/ScghP/lkm123/ReqSqe/MATreq/MaterialDefinitionID

The xml file I am trying to get the data from:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<CPS xmlns="http://www.wonderware.com/wwei/v0201/schemas" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">  
  <AA/>  
  <DA> 
    <ScghP> 
      <ID>1741284-WOG</ID>  
      <Location/>  
      <PublishedDate>2014-03-05 16:03:36</PublishedDate>  
      <StartTime>1/28/2014 12:00:00 AM</StartTime>  
      <EndTime>1/28/2014 1:27:44 AM</EndTime>  
      <lkm123> 
        <ID>54123s0</ID>  
        <OLKM>54123s0 (EPIC Bar)</OLKM>  
        <StartTime>1/28/2014 12:00:00 AM</StartTime>  
        <EndTime>1/28/2014 1:27:44 AM</EndTime>  
        <Priority>0</Priority>  
        <ReqSqe> 
          <ID>000xxxx</ID>  
          <Description>epic item</Description>  
          <EarliestStartTime>1/28/2014 12:00:00 AM</EarliestStartTime>  
          <LatestEndTime>1/28/2014 1:27:44 AM</LatestEndTime>  
          <Duration>0H00M00SPT0</Duration>  
          <MArked/>  
          <MATreq> 
            <MaterialDefinitionID>54123s0</MaterialDefinitionID>  
            <Description>EPIC Bar</Description>  
            <Location/>  
            <Quantity/>  
            <MPRPAZ/>  
            <MPRPAZ/>  
            <LKPK>Required</LKPK> 
          </MATreq>  
          <ReqSqe/>  
          <LKPK>Required</LKPK> 
        </ReqSqe> 
      </lkm123>  
      <Any/> 
    </ScghP> 
  </DA> 
</CPS>
```

The document has been refactored to protect the client's data but the structure for the relevant
components has been preserved.
Thank you for your time and any help offered.

EDIT: So I am trying to define a namespace and fetch the MaterialDefinitionID field using XSLT, the script I have so far is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ww="wonderware.com/wwei/v0201/schemas">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="ww:CPS/ww:DA/ww:ScghP/ww:lkm123/ww:ReqSqe/ww:MATreq">
MaterialDefinitionID:  <xsl:apply-templates select="ww:MaterialDefinitionID"/>;
    </xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Something exactly like this worked for other files that didn't have the namespace issue, but not
here for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

It's the usual namespace issue - `xmlns="http://www.wonderware.com/wwei/v0201/schemas"` in your XML means that all element names in that document that don't have a prefix belong to that namespace, but unprefixed names in XPath refer to elements in *no* namespace.  You need to bind a prefix to the namespace using whatever mechanism your XPath library or tool provides, and then use that prefix in the XPath expression:

```
/ww:CPS/ww:DA/ww:ScghP/ww:lkm123/ww:ReqSqe/ww:MATreq/ww:MaterialDefinitionID
```

(where the `ww` prefix is bound to the `http://www.wonderware.com/wwei/v0201/schemas` URI)

Comment: So if I was using XSLT I would do something like:
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ww="http://www.wonderware.com/wwei/v0201/schemas"> to bind ww and then use ww: in the XPATH later on as you describe?

Comment: or should I define a default namespace like: 
xpath-default-namespace="http://www.wonderware.com/wwei/v0201/schemas"

Comment: @jtempelm `xpath-default-namespace` is an XSLT 2.0 addition.  In XPath 1.0 (and hence in XSLT 1.0) unprefixed names are fixed in the XPath spec to _always_ mean no namespace, so the only way to match namespaced nodes is to use prefixes (or to use tricks like `*[local-name() = 'foo' and namespace-uri() = 'http://example.com/bar']`)